# Prove that CorrectConnSolver is coNP-Complete

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomial-time, co-np

I need to prove that CorrectConnSolver is coNP-Complete where CorrectConnSolver  is defind as follows:
CorrectConnSolve$= \{C | C(G) = 1 \iff G$  is   connected$\}$.
In other words, the
CorrectConnSolver problem is as follows: Given a circuit C, decide if the circuit C solves the
connectivity problem.

I have already proved that CorrectPathHamSolver $\in$ coNP, using search to decision reduction but I can't do similar for CorrectConnSolver becuase to  for connectivity I need all vertex in contrast to the PathHam that requires one path.

I would appreciate any help
Thank you

Comment: If $C$ doesn't solve connectivity that there exists a graph $G$ such that $C(G)$ gives the wrong answer. Since connectivity is in P, this shows that your problem is in coNP.

Comment: Thank you Yuval, that really helped.    Do you have any hint to the completeness part?

Comment: Take the XOR of a circuit for connectivity and some other circuit.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus XOR of which circuit? I'm not sure I understand. Is it a reduction from $\Pi_1 -SAT$?

Comment: It's a reduction from CIRCUIT-SAT.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you, I think I got it, but there is one last thing that bothers me about this reduction.
What happens if $C\in CIRCUIT-SAT$ but there are inputs $x,y$ that are not representing a grpah s.t $C(x)=1 , C(y)=0$? $C\in CIRCUIT-SAT$ but $f(C)$  for some input $z$ that is not a graph, is not depend on the circuit for connectivity and I can't say if the XOR will return 0 or 1.

Comment: You can check in polynomial time whether the input represents a graph.

Comment: I know, I think that I didn't exactly understand your reduction.

IIUIC, the reduction $f$ is from CSAT to $\overline{CorrectConnSolve}$,  s.t $f(c) = (c) XOR (c')$ for some hard coded $c'\in CorrectConnSolve$.
In the direction where $c\in CSAT$, I need to show that $f(c)\in  \overline{CorrectConnSolve}$ .$c\in CSAT$ only says that there is x s.t $c(x)=1$ but it isn't true for all input x. What am I missing?

Comment: Think about what happens if the circuit is not satisfiable.

Comment: It works in that case, but I need to show both cases.

Comment: What happens when the circuit is satisfiable is different from what happens when it is not satisfiable. I’m sorry, but you’ll have to take it from here.